# Why is GetChannel on c# returning a null value? (discord bot)

Tags: c#, discord.net

Can anyone help me on this section of code? Before I say anything else, the "FillerId" isn't actually there in the actual code, it's replaced with the correct channel id of the discord text channel. The error I'm getting with this code is that every time I run this function, it returns an error saying that in line 170 "channel1 is null". I am absolutely sure that I am using the correct channel id.

*Note: for reference I defined the client above this code as "discord001"

```
private void CreateTimerWithOutput(string Message, int MonthWanted, int DayWanted)
{
    var channel1 = discord001.GetChannel(Fillerid);
    CreateTimer(400);
    whaddupTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(NewYearsCheck);
    void NewYearsCheck(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
         DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
         if(today.Month != MonthWanted && today.Day != DayWanted)
         {
             channel1.SendMessage(Message);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, FillerId has red underline. This means error is on your GetChannel method. You should give the exact error you have.

Comment: FillerId is supposed be underlined red since "FillerId" isn't supposed to be there in the first place. In the actual code I put a set of numbers like "1235391" in its place. I just didn't want to write all of it out and didn't have the actual code handy. Basically, the error is not in that part of the code. I'm 100 percent sure of that. When I put the actual numbers in there is no underline. Also as further note, when I use line 161 and 170 in other parts of the code right next to each other instead of apart, they work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running this command and any other methods that get information from Discord after you are certain a connection has been made.

I stored all information (roles, channels, guilds, etc.) within the "Connected" event handler and then accessing them was easy..